# Java barcode generator

Tags: java, android

Currently I'm trying to generate a Barcode for my Android project i want the numbers of the Barcode to appear under the Barcode

The result I get:

[image]

The result I expect:

[image]

```
//It's where I try to get the Barcode as bitmap
bitmap = encodeAsBitmap("00000871", BarcodeFormat.EAN_8, (int) (pageWidth / 72 * 2.54), (int) (pageHeight / 72 * 2.54));


//The function use to the bitmap (got it from github.com)
Bitmap encodeAsBitmap(String contents, BarcodeFormat format, int img_width, int img_height) throws WriterException {
    String contentsToEncode = contents;
    if (contentsToEncode == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = null;
    String encoding = guessAppropriateEncoding(contentsToEncode);
    if (encoding != null) {
        hints = new EnumMap<>(EncodeHintType.class);
        hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, encoding);
    }
    MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
    BitMatrix result;
    try {
        result = writer.encode(contentsToEncode, format, img_width, img_height, hints);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        // Unsupported format
        return null;
    }
    int width = result.getWidth();
    int height = result.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        int offset = y * width;
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
        }
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    return bitmap;
}
```

I use [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) library.

Comment: Actually it helped, is there to know the exact center under the Barcode?

Comment: There is a part in the question after the comment // draw text to the Canvas center. Very likely you can use the same code.